# Detecting domain forwarding with masking with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dns, forwarding

My domain `website.com` is forwarded to `mysite.com/website` with masking (as configured on my godaddy account.)

I want to determine if the site was accessed via `website.com` or `mysite.com/website`.

Unfortunately everything I try returns `mysite.com/website` even when the url bar contains `website.com`. 
Ie. `var url = window.location.href`
Always returns `mysite.com/website` even if the address bar is `website.com`.  So using JavaScript how can I determine what the actual URL was used to access the page and not the translated url. (Somehow the browser knows this information because it displays it in the address bar but when I do 'view source' I only see the translated URL.)  I only need this to work for IE.

Comment: Could you rewrite your question with some spaces and code block?

Comment: `window.location.href` and the URL bar in the browser should be showing exactly the same thing and it should be the same page that is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Do you have frames or something?